# How to draw a bar chart that one series has both positive and negative values in Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts, bar-chart

I am having difficulty in drawing the bar chart as follows using Highcharts:

[image]

For drawing above chart, I guess that it is necessary to make one series has both positive and negative values for one category. But, I do not know how to make a series object in a Highchart option.

My code is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/96uz3dnf/1/) with JSFiddle.

I expected that below series worked, but it did not.

```
series: [{
    name: 'Series 1',
    data: [[-19, 10], [-31, 20]]
}, {
    name: 'Series 2',
    data: [[-10, 33], [-20, 56]]
}, {
    name: 'Series 3',
    data: [[-23, 10], [-30, 13]]
}
```

Also, I saw [a Highchart's demo](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-negative-stack): Bar with negative stack. However, this demo has a different series structure with what I tried; it has only two series: "male or negative" and "female or positive". It seems difficult to have more than two series in this demo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not 100% sure of exactly what values you want to go where, but the concept of how I would solve this, is as follows:

```
series: [{
  name: 'Series 1',
  data: [{x: 0, y: -19}, {x: 0, y: 10}, 
         {x: 1, y: -31}, {x: 1, y: 20}]
}, {
  name: 'Series 2',
  data: [{x: 0, y: 33}, {x: 0, y: -10}, 
         {x: 1, y: 56}, {x: 1, y: -20},]
}, {
  name: 'Series 3',
  data: [{x: 0, y: 10}, {x: 0, y: -23}, 
         {x: 1, y: 13}, {x: 1, y: -30}]
}]
```

Where we still have the same 3 series, but we explicitly state which category the values should belong to, i.e. `x: 0` is category 1, and `x: 1` is category 2.

Working JSfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/kdszxjn3/6/

Comment: Thanks! I never though that data array could take objects. Does a "x" mean a category, am I right? It seems that x:0 indicates Category 1 and Category 2 is linked with x: 1. Just wanna make it clear.

Comment: Ah, you already wrote that explanation below the code part. I get it.